# Firebase Firestore not writing any value

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using **Firebase Firestore**, but it is not storing any value nor giving any error messages.

```
    private var mCustomerDatabase : FirebaseFirestore =  FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    override fun saveUserInfo(uid: String, profile: Database.UserProfile) {
        Log.d(TAG, "saveUserInfo -Inside")

        mCustomerDatabase
            .collection("app")
            .document("users")
            .collection("customers")
            .document(uid)
            .set(profile, SetOptions.merge())
            .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d(TAG, "saveUserInfo - DocumentSnapshot successfully written!") }
            .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "saveUserInfo - Error writing document", e) }

    }
```

**Database.UserProfile** is a data class like the Google "Custom objects" Example (Obviously with other vars):

```
data class City(
    val name: String? = null,
    val state: String? = null,
    val country: String? = null,
    val isCapital: Boolean? = null,
    val population: Long? = null,
    val regions: List<String>? = null
)
```

Rules on **Firebase**:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write, delete, update: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

The strange is that there is no error message, it only does not work. 
The message(saveUserInfo -Inside) is printed, but neither gives the success log not the error log.

It is in a separeted module called **model** - I dont know if this affect, but it shouldnt.

What could it be? - I tested on onCreate and it writes normally with the same code. So I discart the import or config error.

**Update:** I have try every sample code from the documentation and not work. Since there is no message at all What I guess that must be is that I am using a modularized app, the gradle **app** that have the google service is not being found by the implementation of firebase on the module model. The funny thing is that the RealTime database works fine, I think this might be some bug function of FireStone.

I have reported to Google, because even it is some error in my side, it should have some message to say what I did wrong...

I would like to know if there is more people that are having this issue. If you can try to call a Firebase function inside a module called model - You just pass some firebase auth uid to the database and try to create a document with this uid, maybe you can reproduce the error and see if is really a bug

Comment: How to you check the result of your `set()` operation? In the console?

Comment: I checked it on the Android Studio LogCat and Firebase console - Not registering any write and changing the firestore collection

Comment: From which place of your code are you calling the `saveUserInfo()` method?

Comment: From RegisterActivity.kt, I call it when handle a successful firebase auth createUserWithEmailAndPassword and field check(to check if it is not empty or invalid)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too in react js and my mistake was I used the firebase.auth.signout() method and then fired the firestore query.
I removed the auth.signout() and it worked

Answer (score 0):

With me, problem was domain. Go to console / Authentication / Authorized domains and check is your domain in list. If not, write is not working (with no error).